# How to plan a task to run after another already running task in bash?

Tags: bash, job-control, jobs

I'm looking for something like `command1 ; command2` i.e. how to run `command2` after `command1` but I'd like to plan execution of `command2` when `command1` is already running.

It can be solved by just typing the `command2` and confirming by Enter supposed that the `command1` is not consuming standard input and that the `command1` doesn't produce to much text on output making it impractical to type (typed characters are blended with the `command1` output).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Generally what I do is: **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> `fg && command2`**

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to pause it and let you type more in the shell.
2. Optionally `bg`, to resume command1 in the background while you type out command2.
3. `fg && command2` to resume command1 in the foreground and queue up command2 afterwards if command1 succeeds. You can of course substitute `;` or `||` for the `&&` if you so desire.

Answer (score 24):

1. start a command

   ```
   command1
   ```
2. pause the execution by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
3. find the job number of the paused command (it's usually already printed to console when to console when to command is paused) by executing

   ```
   jobs
   ```
4. let `command1` continue in background

   ```
   bg
   ```
5. plan execution of `command2` to await finish of `command1`

   ```
   wait -n <command1 job number> ; command2
   ```

Documentation [Job Control Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html)

Comment: You can 'accept' your own answer (click the tick icon) into order to show other users that there is a good answer to your question.

Comment: @sudodus Own answer can be accepted at earliest 2 days after the question was asked. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/

Comment: In simple cases I sometimes control-z then use `fg ; command`.  Or even `fg && command` to only run the 2nd command / pipeline if the first one was successful.  (You can still use `bg` while thinking / typing, if it doesn't spew text on the terminal.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what this approach offers beyond the typical `command1; command2` syntax. Could you please clarify this for me?

Comment: You can use `$!` to get the pid of backgrounded job.

Comment: `command1 & proceed_after=$!` then when you've got the next command figured out `wait -n $proceed_after; command 2`

Answer (score 8):

There are several alternatives.

- **With one ampersand**, 'push to background', the second program starts after the first one starts, but they will probably run alongside each other.

  ```
  command1 & command2
  ```
- **With two ampersands**, 'logical and', the second program will start only if the first program finished successfully.

  ```
  command1 && command2
  ```
- **With a semicolon** separating the commands in the command line, the the second program will start, when the first program finished, even if it failed or was interrupted.

  ```
  command1 ; command2
  ```
- You can use **`wait <PID>`** to wait for the first command to finish, if it is already running from the same shell (in the same terminal window).
- Otherwise if the first command is already running from another shell (in another window), you can use a small **while loop using ps to check if the PID is still found by `ps`**. When it is no longer found, the second command will be started.

  This demo example for `bash` checks if `top` is running via the PID, and runs the command

  ```
  echo "*** $USER, I am ready now ***"
  ```

  if/when `top` is no longer running.

  ```
  pid=$(ps -A|grep top|cut -d ' ' -f 1); \
  while [ "$pid" != "" ]; do ps -A|grep "$pid" > /dev/null; \
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then sleep 5;else pid=""; fi; done; \
  echo "*** $USER, I am ready now ***"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way is just to let command 1 start in the background and then have command 2 start either in the background or in the foreground. The full command is this:

```
command1 & command2
```

`&` is not a connector between these two commands. It can be used with `command1` alone to have it started in the background:

```
command1 &
```

And this is right syntax for starting both commands in the background:

```
command1 & command2 &
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't mind if commands are running in background or foreground. I'd like to run them serially (one starts when the previous one ends) and I'd like to plan the execution of the second one when the first one is already running.

Comment: @czerny So you want the second one to start while the first one is still running, when it's already finished, or?

Comment: I'd like the second command to be started when the first command finishes

Comment: @czerny Then just use `;`. Or do you want to do something while the first one is still running?

Answer (score -3):

If you have a choice to use two terminals, here's what you can do:

- Assuming you are already running command1 in a terminal (let's call it terminal1)
- Start a new terminal (let's call it terminal2)
- Find process ID of command1 (let's call it command1_pid). In terminal2, run command `ps -ef | grep <command1>` (you might want to properly form the filter string in grep command so that you do not accidently find another process having  as a substring).
- Run command `wait <command1_pid> ; command2`

Basically, `wait` is a bash built-in command that waits until the provided PIDs exit and then return. You are simply delegating your waiting for command1 to finish, on to bash's `wait` command.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. Running `wait` in different terminal outputs following error message: `bash: wait: pid 19531 is not a child of this shell`.

Comment: @czerny That's normal, I don't think this answer was tested.  POSIX `wait` system calls only work on child processes, so one bash process can't wait for the children of a different instance of bash.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html#ERRORS says `wait` and `waitpid` return with `ECHILD` error status in this case.